# How to save the EditText box as image into the Gallery

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-image, android-gallery

In my application I have used the EditText box, Inside the EditText I have to  type some letter anywhere ,After that I will put some images into the edit text In Anywhere I will pick the images from the Gallery,After that I want to save the entire Edit Text as the image in my SD card or Gallery.

Comment: did u try something???

Comment: No, I hav'nt  try can u tel any suggestion to save this EditText.

Comment: first you will have to try it by urself..we will only suggest u or solve ur error..

Comment: I did convert the edit text as bitmap after that i save but its not working.

Comment: so show me ur code,..what u tried?

Comment: Before that i want to take image from gallery into the edit text,also type something in edit text  u have idea.

Comment: Do come to the chat page im accessing my friend account.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_et);
et.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
et.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(et.getDrawingCache());
et.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
et.buildDrawingCache(false);
```

Now you have this EditText as image, try something to save it to file.

Comment: I have an error on this line            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90);

Comment: 1) I do not see your code;
2) try to use private Bitmap b; (not a final)